# I want to be able to manipulate objects in class 'phylo' - ie. round/ turn my bootstrap values from decimals (.998) into percentages (99%)

Tags: r, phylogeny, ape-phylo

I am using RStudio, programs ape and `phytools`. I've generated a tree with 500 bootstrap replicates stored in an object of class `phylo`.

Where `cw` is the name of my tree, I've tried the following:

```
round(cw, digits = 2)
```

and I get the following error message:

> Error in round(cw, digits = 2) : 
>     non-numeric argument to mathematical function

I feel like it's probably a very simple manipulation but I'm not sure how to get there.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell without a reproducible example but I guess that your bootstrap scores are probably stored in the `$node.label` subset of your tree.

You can try the following:

```
## Are the bootstraps in the $node.label object?
if(!is.null(cw$node.label)) {
    ## Are they as character or numeric?
    class(cw$node.label)
}
```

If they are numeric values:

```
cw$node.label <- round(cw$node.label, digits = 2)
```

If they are characters, you can probably coerce them (that can produce some NAs)

```
cw$node.label <- round(as.numeric(cw$node.label), digits = 2)
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! A similar iteration worked for me:                          cw$node.label<- as.numeric(cw$node.label)
cw$node.label<- round(cw$node.label,digits=2)
cw$node.label<- (cw$node.label)*100
"Now we append labels to the tree"
cw$node.label #check it again!
nodelabels(cw$node.label,node=1:cw$Nnode+Ntip(cw),
           adj=c(2,-2),frame="none", cex=0.5) # adds bootstraps
cw$node.label

Comment: A `phylo` object is actually a `list`. You can look out in how manipulate `list` elements.